# Why did I fail this Low Quality Review Audit?

Tags: support, review-audits

I recently failed this audit (https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14244438).
[image]

The answer was apparently "abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable – readers will find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful." I don't know anything about Java performance tuning tools, and a look at the linked site reveals that it does at least offer some Java performance monitoring tools (https://www.dynatrace.com/technologies/java-monitoring/). I didn't think it was spam, and it seemed like a reasonable attempt an answering the (admittedly off-topic) question.

Was I wrong about it being spam? Or should I just be voting to delete answers to off-topic questions?

Comment: I can't see the answer; can you please copy it here?  (Was it a link-only answer?)

Answer (score 7):

It probably *was* spam. But that's the problem with questions like that: they allow spam to be valid answers.

I've removed that question from the site and cleared the spam flag so that it won't be used again as an audit.